# Send Request to a website in My PC local Host

Tags: php, windows, apache, xampp, localhost

I have a offline website installed on my localhost PC , I am using xampp with apache. I installed everything and I can access the website from browsers normally. But when I am trying to send any PHP POST or GET requests to this localhost from anywhere like PostMan or any other online website I got connection Refused Error. Also its happen with file_get_contents.

I don't have much experience in Windows firewall or apache configuration so I need advice for what can I do?

Comment: Localhost only works on the same computer. It's a local address. If you want to access your local site from some online server, then you would need to configure your computer/web server/firewall/router to accept incoming requests on the correct port(s) (something like port forwarding in the router for port 80 and/or 443) and then use your external IP to access it from the internet. However, if you're not sure how to do this in a secure manner, you could open up your computer and network for all kinds of security issues.

Comment: "I have a offline website" - If it needs to be accessible from "online tools" then your website needs to be "online" also. This is really a networking issue, probably better suited to https://superuser.com. "Also its happen with file_get_contents" - it shouldn't, unless you are making requests to a URL-path that can't be resolved locally.

Answer (score 0):

it was a CSF firewall error from the online server side. it was not allow me to send the requests outside the server without whitelisted the requested server :)

Thanks